# How do I substitute an arbitrary inline unicode character with its representation in hexadecimal?

Tags: c#, .net, utf

How do I convert to the following string from "hello  ️‍️ world" to "hello 1F610 1F441 FE0F 200D 1F5E8 FE0F   world".

What I have tried:

```
    var str = "hello  ️‍️ world";
    var regex = new Regex(@"(\p{Cs}\p{Cs})");
    var newStr = regex.Replace(str, m => UnicodeToString(m.Groups[1].Value));

    string UnicodeToString(string value)
    {
        var b = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(value);
        var str = string.Join("", b.Select(x => {  return x.ToString("x");}));
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Strings in C# are by default Unicode (UTF-8, MS is just calling it Unicode) so the `Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes()`is not doing what you expect it to

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear possible to use regular expressions to do what I want.  I was able to use [unicode.net](https://github.com/neosmart/unicode.net) and loop through the codepoints to get all of the unicode elements I need.

```
var seq = "hello  ️‍️ world".Codepoints();
foreach(var cp in seq)
{
    if(cp.AsUtf32 < 127) 
    {
        sb.Append(cp.AsString());
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(cp.ToString().Replace("U+", "") + " ");
    }
}
sb.ToString().Dump();
```

Output:
hello 1F601  1F441 FE0F 200D 1F5E8 FE0F  world